# How can I horizontally align the text in separate block elements?

Tags: css, alignment

I realize that when I center text, its enveloping element becomes as wide as possible to be able to display the text in the true center with correct linebreaks and alignment.

But, what if I want to align a subtitle on the left hand side of centered text?

[image: desired situation, 'test' lined out with 'Lorem']

In the above image I simulated the desired outcome with a margin on the 'test' element, but is there a way to dynamically align this?

My code:

```css
* {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.contain {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 350px;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.content {
    background: #ff000030;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: fit-content;
}

.sub {
    /* margin-left:30px; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
            <div class="sub">test</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If at all possible, I'd like to avoid using javascript for this, and just find a pure css solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could get the effect you want only if the "test" text is before the centered one, and uses an `inline-block` display; you can test varying the centered text to change the position:

```css
* {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}

.contain {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 350px;
}

.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 80px 0;
}

.content {
    background: #ff000030;
    font-size: 32px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: fit-content;
}

.sub {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="content">
            <div class="sub">test</div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sitametameta amet.  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's it! I'd fiddled around with display styles before, but changing the order in the html is what actually solves this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A solution from the future using the Anchor Positioning: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-anchor-position-1/#anchoring

Not ready for production but can be tested on Chrome with experimental flag enabled.

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.contain {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 350px;
}

.wrap {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.content {
  background: #ff000030;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  width: fit-content;
}

/* we use the before pseudo element (an inline element) as the anchor */
.content::before {
  content: "";
  anchor-name: --align;
}

.sub {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: anchor(--align 0%);
  left: anchor(--align 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="contain">
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="content">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
      <div class="sub">test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately not a usable solution, but interesting read, good to know.